# Adding Image to Java Applet

Tags: java, image, swing, applet, awt

I am having a problem with my image not being displayed on my applet, here is the code, all pertaining to the image;

```
 Image globe;

//Adding Image in init()
Image globe = getImage (getCodeBase (), "C:/Users/Andrew/Downloads/Computer Science/globe.jpg");
//later in code

 public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString ("'The Best Travel Agency in the world' - John Travelta", 400, 675);
        g.drawImage(globe, 0, 100, this);
    } // paint method

    public boolean action (Event e, Object o)
    {
        if (e.target == DomRep)
        {
            String DomRepBox = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Please Enter your name: ");
        }
        return true;
    }
```

this is the error I am receiving;

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.copyImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.copyImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(Unknown Source)
    at CPT.paint(CPT.java:129)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You should avoid using absolute paths, such as `C:/Users/Andrew/Downloads/Computer Science/globe.jpg`, especially when using applets.  Instead, you need to use a relative path based on the relationship between the image and the applet

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what the getImage() method is, but normally you import images like this:

```
try {
    globe = ImageIO.read(new URL("URL_OF_FILE.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Alright, now I am getting a "throwIOException" error. Any ideas?

Comment: Given that this is an applet, referencing the image through an absolute path is a bad idea.  Given that this is applet, you won't have access to the underlying file system, so you, unless it's singed and the local permission allow it, you won't be able to use `File`.

Comment: You have to surround it with a try catch. I modified the above code to incorporate it. MadProgrammer brings up a good point too. Store your images in your program's working directory.

Comment: Worked perfectly! And thanks for the advice, will do!

Comment: `ImageIO.read(new File(..` That will fail as soon as the applet is deployed.  Applets and files don't mix.  To load a `File`, the applet would need to be fully trusted, and even then the image would need to be present on disks of the the **user's PC** as opposed to the server.

Comment: Sorry, I've never worked with applets before. Using a URL instead and uploading the file to the web should work.

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Given this resource is apparently supplied by the applet developer, it will need to be on the server, and accessed as you first indicated..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Didn't really feel there was enough context to know "where" the image was coming from, in the end, it was all a reference issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I made some inferences from the `Computer Science` part of the path that this was not an image the end user was going to supply.  Perhaps I assumed too much (and the teacher is expecting ***way*** too much).

Answer (score 1):

```
Image globe = getImage (getCodeBase(), "relative/path/to/globe.jpg");
```

Should work just fine for an applet.  If the applet is in the same directory as the HTML, this is even easier.

```
Image globe = getImage (getDocumentBase(), "globe.jpg");
```

Comment: I've also seen `ImageIO.read((getCodeBase(), "relative/path/to/globe.jpg"))` but that's probably going beyond the scope of the question ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer That *is* better for error reporting, I just thought I'd stick closer to the form of the original post.  Also, those relative paths ore often tricky for newbies, hence the 2nd suggestion.